# Facetime with more than one apple device

Tags: facetime

Is it possible for four people to make a Facetime call with the following setup?

- one using an iPhone 4,
- one using an iPad 2 (both of which have the same email address)
- another two people who have independent email addresses

Comment: a 4 way conference call?

Answer (score 1):

*Do you want to place calls between two iDevices using the same Apple ID?*

By default, all devices connected to the same Apple ID utilize the primary email address associated with that Apple ID. This means they'll all ring if a FaceTime call is placed to that email address. It also means you can't place a class between two devices, just as you can't use one home phone to place a call to your house and answer it with another phone. But luckily, Apple has provided a rather easy workaround for placing FaceTime calls on the same Apple ID.

**To place a FaceTime call between two of your Apple devices, you will simply need to add a new email address to one of the devices. This will allow FaceTime to differentiate between the two and place a call to a specific device.**

You can add a new email address to FaceTime in the *iPad settings.* Simply select FaceTime from the left-side menu and tap your finger where it reads "Add Another Email..."

Once you add a new email address, you must verify it by going to that email's inbox. There should be an email waiting for you from Apple with a link that will verify the email address.

Source - http://ipad.about.com/od/iPad_Guide/ss/How-To-Use-FaceTime-On-The-iPad_2.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. I think at the moment, Apple's Facetime only allows a one-to-one chat. So 2 people using different Apple ID's. If they had group chat, they would definitely have posted it up on their website, with instructions on how to do it on their support site.

Comment: I think i've made my point :)